# Splitting a polygon into circles

Tags: qgis, polygon, circle

I’m fairly new to QGIS.

I have a polygon that I need to split up into circles. I have the following requirements:

1. I must be able to specify the radius for these circles, for example 2 km, so that they’re all the same size.
2. The circles may overlap, but should do so as little as possible.
3. Together the circles must cover the entire polygon, and it’s preferred that they cover as little of the area outside the polygon as possible.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: A nice question but it would be much nicer if you can provide some of your ideas and efforts in solving this issue. Because this question besides a dull usage of software involves a mathematical problem aka circle packing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is no attempt at any optimizing.

1. Create a hexagon grid
2. Create circles from it using minimum enclosing circles
3. Intersect this with the input polygon layer
   [image]

If you create a model you can add grid size as an input variable which you set each time you execute the model